# main.exe has stopped working in code blocks

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a code I wrote for bubble sort. I gave a comment `//this line` due to which I'm unable to run this program. Every time the first element of the `array` needs to be stored in 'temp'.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int arr[7]={7,8,5,2,4,6};
    int temp;

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        temp=arr[0];  //this line.

        for(int j=0;j<7-i;j++)
        {
            if(temp<arr[j])
                temp=arr[j];
            else
                swap(arr[j],arr[j-i]);
        }
    }

    for(int k=0;k<7;k++)
    {
        cout<<arr[k]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your crash, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problem, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially, if you have a crash you should use a debugger to catch it and see when and where in your code it happens, and then examine the values of all involved variables to verify that they are valid and okay.

Comment: `swap(arr[j],arr[j-i]);` if i=6 and j=0, it will make your program crash.

Comment: yeah, indexing flaw there..  Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort , there is pseudocode.

Comment: @NoEm It will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which can often be a cause for crashes. But it's not guaranteed to crash.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just checked in codeblocks IDE, it crashed when called `swap` function.

Comment: @No Em depends on compiler and runtime, mine didn't... it's some assert state, I presume. but still, those loops are wrong for bubble sort

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude each time I see that header include I can't get out of my head the thought that "bits" folder is named so because it's compiler's naughty bits...that never should be public

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but do you intend to create an array of seven elements but only initialise 6 of them? The last element will just be default initialised to 0.

Answer (score 1):

There were some issue with your program:

- Array size should be **6** instead of **7**
- The for loop **condition** was incorrect
- `swap(arr[j],arr[j-i])` will break when `j-i` is less than **0**(for instance i=1, j=0).

**Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int arr[6]={7,8,5,2,4,6};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5-i;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
                swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
        }
    }
    for(int k=0;k<6;k++)
        cout<<arr[k]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/2msfbx)

Comment: that's essentially same as my answer, but it doesn't degrade from  O(n^2) to O(n) if array is sorted and uses magic numbers.

Comment: My Bad I didn't check your answer -_- @Swift. But I tried to keep the code similar to the user's code, also mentioning its issues! You may take the accepted answer for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem flipped  for() loops over... what I got - not the most elegant solution, but I stick to the same tools you're using. Mostly. I could make it as template and it would work with any appropriate container. `std::sort`  sometimes implemented like that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
   bool swapped;
   for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
     swapped = false;
     for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
     {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
        {
           std::swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);
           swapped = true;
        }
     }

     // no elements were swapped, array already sorted.
     if (!swapped) break;
   }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {7,8,5,2,4,6};

    bubbleSort(arr, std::size(arr));

    for( auto v : arr )
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In  C++11 and later `<algorithm>` can be replaced by `<utility>`, it's just for swap/size.

Comment: In C++98 or later, you can also replace this whole mess with `std::sort` :)

Comment: or `std::stable_sort` if a stable sorting algorithm is required (bubble sort is stable)

Comment: @Lundin  Defeats purpose of "write bubble sort" ,  and sot isn't necessary implemented as bubble

Comment: My whole point here is rather that "write bubble sort" fills no purpose in the first place, outside of algorithm theory.

Comment: @Lundin not true.. you never wrote for controller or for signal-processing hardware then. no vector, no std::string, no std::sort. AT best, if that's user-friendly thing like Arduino, you get simple Array and String classes.  Write everything youself, optimize for particular controller, because ALU would be very exotic thing

Comment: @Swift I have written bare metal signal-processing programs... and I have also written home-made implementations of quicksort & mergesort. Where exactly does bubble sort come in? Yeah I've used bubble sort for things like median-3 or median-5 digital filters with very little data, but I would hardly call that sorting.

Comment: @Lundin A) from original question, with particular topic  , answering use "std::sort" is a non-answer, b) depends what expectations of input data are and c) it is effective if it can be inlined and stay fully in stack or registers, little set , your  application fits in those. d) It's  one of three main questions asked when you apply for job..at least from my experience or from anyone I know (different country, different rules could be)